# Reducing Unity Android build size

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the Unity mobile Android APK build size to below 150mb, but it's currently at 170mb. I'm reading through many online docs, but can't find anything that so far reduced my build size. (For reference, I'm creating a "Virtual OS" where many virtual apps are bundled into one, and can be experienced in many different environments, so that increases size.)

My main question is, **how can I find the biggest file size "offenders" in my project**? Unity's doc tells me to look into the Editor Log's Build Report list, but the files mentioned in the top there (as "uncompressed", e.g. my 20k something PNG becomes a 1+mb file in that list), mainly textures, do not actually help when I next time remove them in another test build. Neither does it relevantly help when I change the Android texture setting to something more highly compressed (e.g. 1024 max Mitchell, which I had for most of my files anyway).

I've tried both APK building, as well as ABB, but both results are quite big. (Switching the API Compatibility Level from .NET 4x to 2 doesn't help either.) I'm compiling to 64bit architecture.

Edit: A first big improvement became removing an (unneeded for Android) Oculus directory (and accompanying Package Manager packages). But this wasn't shown in any charts.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: "Analyze APK" within Android Studio

Comment: Thank you! Doing that now, I see Assets -> Bin -> Data contains the bulk of the size. Inside it, I see a whole lot of *.resource files of varying MBs. How do I now understand what those resources tie back to in my project, to optimize?